# Why are objects visible to all threads, while a reading thread might not see a value written by another thread on a timely basis?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

From java in a nutshell

> In Java,   all Java application threads in a process have their own
> stacks (and local variables) but **share a single heap**. This makes it
> very easy to **share objects between threads**, as all that is required is
> to pass a reference from one thread to another.
>
> This leads to a general design principle of Java—that **objects are
> visible by default**. If I have a reference to an object, I can copy
> it and hand it off to another thread with no restrictions. A Java
> reference is essentially a typed pointer to a location in memory—and
> threads  share  the  same  address  space,  so  visible  by  default
> is  a  natural model.

From Java   Concurrency  in Practice

> Visibility is subtle because the things that can go wrong are so
> counterintuitive. In a single-threaded environment, if you write a
> value to a variable and later read that variable with no intervening
> writes, you can expect to get the same value back. This seems only
> natural. It may be hard to accept at ﬁrst, but when the reads and
> writes occur in different threads, this is simply not the case. In
> general,
> **there is no guarantee that the reading thread will see a value written by another thread on a timely basis, or even at all.** In
> order to ensure visibility of memory writes across threads, you must
> use synchronization.
>
> When a thread reads a variable without synchronization, it may see a stale value.

So why does Java in a Nutshell says objects are visible to all threads, while Java Concurrency in Practice says no guarantee that a reading thread sees a value written by another thread on a timely basis? They don't seem consistent.

Thanks.

Comment: Java In A Nutshell is wrong, or at least glossing over some subtle, but really important, details. They should have said something like "all objects are visible, maybe, at some point, and even then you might only see some of them -- unless you're careful about how you hand them off to the other thread."

Comment: All objects are visible, but it doesn't mean that different threads see the most updated value... ;) read move about the keyword *volatile*

Comment: @alfasin since shared objects are stored in the heap shared by threads, why some threads might not see the most updated value by other threads?

Comment: @Ben because threads may have cached values of these objects

Comment: The Java in a Nutshell statement is correct and that's not a Java issue. It applies to C# and C++ as well. There is memory and it can either be accessed (if committed) or not (if reserved). The Concurrency book is also correct, because it talks about a data race, which occurs when you read and write to the same memory in parallel.

Comment: This is especially true on multi-core CPUs. Each core has its own cache of memory, and a big part of what makes your computer zoom is that computers are good at using that cache. But that also means that two cores might have the same object cached, and unless the cores are told otherwise, they're not going to slow down in order to sync those caches up.

Comment: I even doubt the stack statement is correct. If (whatever way) you get a valid pointer to another thread's stack, you would be able to write there, because the OS which handles the memory has declared it as writeable.

Comment: @ThomasWeller There is no way to get a pointer to a thread's stack in the Java Language, hence the statement is correct. Moreover, there is no way to access any data on another thread's stack, data could only be shared via heap, and this is that the first quote explains.

Comment: @kan: which is just a limitation of the Java language and is not realted to the memory protection provided by the OS. With some JNI it should be possible.

Comment: @ThomasWeller True, but JNI is not Java Language, it is part of Java Platform, so the statement is still correct. And I don't see it is as limitation, but restriction.

Comment: @kan: of course it's good that Java does it like that.

Answer (score 1):

*"So why does Java in a Nutshell says objects are visible to all threads"* -->
As your quote says, in Java objects are allocated on the heap. A 'global' heap available for the entire JVM. Whereas in other languages (e.g. C++) objects can also be allocated on a stack. Objects on a heap can be passed to other threads, using different stacks. Objects on a stack can only be used on the thread using the same stack, as the stack's content will change beyond control of another thread.

*"while Java Concurrency in Practice says no guarantee that a reading thread sees a value written by another thread on a timely basis?"* -> This is another issue, as this is about values of memory locations. Though they are reachable compilers and CPUs try to optimize reading from or writing to this memory locations and will heavily cache the value by assuming "I'm the only one reading and writing to this memory location". So if one thread modifies a memory location's value the other thread does not know it has changed and will not read it new. This makes the program much faster. By declaring a variable `volatile` you are telling the  compiler that another thread may change the value at will and the compiler will use this to create code that doesn't cache the value.

Finally, multithreading is much more difficult than adding `volatile`, or using `synchronized`, one really needs to dive into the topic of the issues you *will* encounter when using multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, all Java application threads in a process have their own
>   stacks (and local variables) but share a single heap. This makes it
>   very easy to share objects between threads, as all that is required is
>   to pass a reference from one thread to another.
>
> This leads to a general design principle of Java—that objects are
>   visible by default.

I suppose that these statements are strictly true ... but they are misleading because they don't convey the whole truth.  For example, what does the author mean when he says *"...that objects are visible by default."*

Any thread executing on a Java JVM does not have de facto visibility to all the objects on the JVM's heap.  If we define visibility as *"the ability to access by reference"*, then a thread only has visibility to objects:

- whose references have been published to that thread
- whose references are in static fields or fields of objects to which the thread has access

In fact, an important and commonly used thread safety policy in Java concurrent programming is *thread confinement*.  If a thread holds a reference to an object to which only it has access and which is not published to any other thread, then that object is thread safe.  That object can be safely mutated by the thread in which it is confined without any further regard to visibility and atomicity ... as long as it is correctly thread confined.

In other words, an object that is thread confined, no matter where it is on the JVM heap, is not visible to any other thread that may be running on that same JVM by virtue of being inaccessible.

> since shared objects are stored in the heap shared by threads, why
>   some threads might not see the most updated value by other threads?

In this age of multi-core processors, each CPU on which a JVM may be running has its own levels of local cache memory that no other core can see.  This gets to the heart of why values written to variables in one thread are not guaranteed to be visible to another thread:  the Java Memory Model makes no guarantees when values written by one thread will become visible to other threads because it does not specify when cached values will be written back from cache to memory.

It is, in fact, usual for the unsynchronized access of values to be stale (or inconsistent) when those values are accessed by many threads.  Depending on the state transition that is occurring, thread safety in a concurrent environment in which many threads may be accessing the same value, may require:

- mutual exclusion
- atomicity protection
- visibility guarantees
- or all of the above

in order to achieve a thread safety policy that allows your program to be correct.

Comment: Aren't almost all modern CPUs cache coherent? Meaning that all threads always see the latest write, regardless of whether the value is fetched from the cache or the RAM?